# Create table query with pandas using read_sql with 'sqlite://' error

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.read_sql('create table test (ints int)', 'sqlite://')
```

For which I get:

```
File "/home/bla/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 436, in read_sql
    chunksize=chunksize,
  File "/home/bla/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1235, in read_query
    data = result.fetchall()
  File "/home/bla/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/result.py", line 1221, in fetchall
    e, None, None, self.cursor, self.context
  File "/home/bla/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1485, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/home/bla/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 153, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/bla/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/result.py", line 1216, in fetchall
    l = self.process_rows(self._fetchall_impl())
  File "/home/bla/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/result.py", line 1167, in _fetchall_impl
    return self._non_result([])
  File "/home/bla/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/result.py", line 1172, in _non_result
    "This result object does not return rows. "
sqlalchemy.exc.ResourceClosedError: This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically.
```

Am I misusing the dialect somehow?

From what I gathered, the cursor is being closed and `None`d via `ResultProxy._soft_close()`.

This is then followed by a `result.fetchall()` in Pandas' `sql.py`

Comment: `read_sql` is to read a table from your database, not to execute a create table statement

Comment: Thanks! Can I somehow create a table with pandas over sqlite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a table with pandas over sqlalchemy can be done via `df.to_sql()`:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sa

engine = sa.create_engine('sqlite://')

# Create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'ints': [6,7]})

# Optionally specify SQLAlchemy types of columns
dtype={'ints': sa.Integer}

# This will create a table if one doesn't exist
df.to_sql('test', engine, if_exists='replace', index=False, dtype=dtype)  

# Check that data matches
res = pd.read_sql('select * from test', engine)
assert ((res == df).eq(True).all()[0])
```